# Elegant way to have dynamic form action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with many attributes and the default `action = "controller_action_name/default_1/default_2"`. Depending on the user's choice these params needs to change to the corresponding path and I'm making it through javascript.

I have an impression that this is not the best practice in Rails because it seems a little messy.

I tried to update these params directly on the controller action:

```
params[:default_1] = params[:search][:param_a] # param_a and param_b are two input values from te form "search"
params[:default_2] = params[:search][:param_b]
```

to get the URL ".../controller_action_name/param_a/param_b"

And the destination URL didn't change, even changing the params on the controller...are there another way? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to do something by outlining your routes. Go to the link below and search "3.7 HTTP Verb Constraints" on the page, and read on(It's lengthy but informative). 

REF: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I'm not sure how it can solve my problem. Constraints only restricts the string possibilities but can't update it passing parameters...